# Best media player/center that works well with FTP server

Tags: ftp, media-player, media-center-extender

Im looking for a Media center/player that lets me connect to my FTP server. This is what I know so far.
XBMC is great however its too much of a media center and when working in word its anoyly hard to change the song.

VLC does have ftp capabilities, however they are not easy, and you can only direct to only one file and not to a directory.

I would like something with a iTunes like UI that plays directly from my FTP server.

Thanks!

Comment: Why FTP? Perhaps there are better ways to go about this...

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows and Ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

[Ashampoo® Media Player+](http://www2.ashampoo.com/webcache/html/1/product_2_0014___EUR.htm) is freeware.

This is what it says:

> **Online folders and files:**   
> You can include FTP folders and web files
>   in your playlists. The contents of FTP
>   folders are updated automatically,
>   just like local folders! You can even
>   listen to and view many audio and
>   video formats online in real time,
>   without downloading the files to your
>   computer first.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I've read about that one. Should be good, never used it.

Comment: link is dead. Can you update it?

Comment: @Woeitg: The product seemed to have disappeared. Sorry, but this answer from 2009 is now dead.

Answer (score 1):

[MediaPortal](http://www.team-mediaportal.com/) - Been using this for a couple of years now.

Answer (score 1):

here's an entirely different approach:

use **[NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/features.html)** to mount remote storage (such as FTP servers) as a local hard drive and then use your media player of choice to play media files.

> NetDrive supports direct file
>   operation in mapped drive. You can run
>   any .exe files in remote server from
>   your Windows explorer. To watch a
>   movie file in your remote server, you
>   just need to double click it.

*NetDrive free for personal use.*

Answer (score 0):

Mplayer if I well remember could do that !!!

Answer (score -1):

I know it is old but first match in Google so:

KODI

https://kodi.tv/

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.